# Does anyone know of a good framework or application to rapidly build front-ends for MySQL and PHP based web applications?

Tags: php, mysql, user-interface, web-applications, frameworks

Can anyone recommend a good, visually attractive PHP framework or application to rapidly create back office / admin interfaces to MySQL based applications.

I generally have to build bespoke back office UIs for every PHP web based application I write and wondered if there is an easier way of quickly building a web front-end to MySQL data.

**Update**
Just to be clear I'm not looking for a framework to write code per say or an IDE, I'm looking for something to rapidly build rich graphical web interfaces.

Comment: I highly doubt you'll get anything beyond the usual candidates, in which case you can go straight to http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Comment: I posted a related question on why there are so many PHP, Java frameworks and none with UI editing capabilities.. might want to check it out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190666/what-good-are-frameworks-without-proper-ide-environment-php-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for something to rapidly build rich graphical web interfaces.

The thing is, in order to have a rich UI in the browser, you either need third party plugins like Flash or Silverlight or use the traditional combination of HTML, CSS and a whole lot of JavaScript, because that is how the *behavior* and Ajax capabilities get into the UI components of a [RIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application). A serverside framework capable of creating a rich UI would have to know how to create all this. Frameworks like this do exist ([GWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) comes to mind), but there is no dedicated framework for this in the PHP world (at least not to my knowledge).

The [notable PHP frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) all offer rapid application development out of the box. Some of them, like Cake, Symfony and ZF (don't know about CI) even offer [make-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) tools to create controllers, models and view scripts through code generation, speeding up development time even more. Feature-wise, there is very little you will miss in any of them. However, none of them give you rich UIs like that of [ExtJS](http://extjs.com/), [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org) or [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) (to name some JS framewoks) out of the box.

The three closest things to what you are looking for would be to

- use the available PHP wrappers for [Ext.direct](http://www.extjs.com/products/direct/?ref=family) or
- [Zend Framework's Dojo components](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dojo.html) or
- [Zend Framework with Flex/AMF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_php.html).

In addition, there is frameworks like [PRADO](http://www.xisc.com/) which use their own templating language to create rich components or [framework that use XUL](http://www.moztips.com/wiki/index.pcgi?page=XulPhpMySQL) to use the browser's native UI components. I'd categorize them as, well.. not so common.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are talking about an IDE (programming application), or a PHP framework.

If you are talking about IDEs, Zend (http://zend.com) or Eclipse (//http://www.eclipse.org/) are the two major IDEs out there. Zend has its own framework and Eclipse allows you to use whatever framework you choose. There is also, Aptana (http://aptana.org) and Adobe's Dreamweaver.

As for PHP frameworks, Zend has its own, but there are also CodeIgniter (http://www.codeigniter.com) and CakePHP (http://www.cakephp.org). I prefer codeigniter because its more efficient and its documentation is amazing. Although CakePHP has its benefits as well, especially for rapid database development.

Comment: I was referring to frameworks or software to rapidly build web user interfaces. Codeigniter sounds interesting.

Comment: CodeIgniter is definitely my choice. My company had me research all different languages and frameworks to make a decision on what to use, of which I chose it, so I do have some experience in at least choosing the software. As for an IDE, I can't really speak...I use vim with custom macros.

Comment: How someone can prefer code messes like Cake or CI over Symfony and ZF is beyond me

Comment: Well, first off, i work for an open source company, so anything that constricted users to particular programs (especially paid ones) was not desirable.
And CodeIgniter's documentation is amazing, not something I could say for Symfony when I reviewed it. That's a HUGE issue when you're trying to build an open source community.

Comment: @Gordon Why don't you suggest something else then?

Comment: @camsoft I already did in the comments to your question. Before there was any of the answers I told you you would get :)

Comment: @ocdcoder especially how does Symfony (or ZF) restrict you to particular programs? And how is http://www.symfony-project.org/doc/1_4/ less comprehensive than CIs docs?

Comment: @Gordon I'm not a big fan of function lists. Compare the two: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfDatabase (SF) vs. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html (CI)

Although you are right, SF's docs are comprehensive, but not "amazing" like i described CI's :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think codeigniter is a good choice. Cakephp has very ambiguous documentation...

Comment: Why is CI a good choice? Because you are used to it? What RAD features does it offer?

Comment: CodeIgniter is very flexible, its documented tremendously well and has a pretty good community around it (which love to share existing libraries). Its also a lot more efficient than Cake.

Some consider a downside of CI to be that you have to create your own db interactions. But I consider it a good thing, because my line of work rarely uses basic database designs. So it offers me the flexibility I need.

Answer (score 1):

Embarcadero's [Delphi For PHP](http://embarcadero.com/products/delphi-for-php) is quite good. It uses the [VCL For PHP](http://www.qadram.com/vcl4php/) framework, and provides an easy-to-use, drag-and-drop interface for creating the web applications.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to the other answers. You asked for framework or application.
PHPMaker is an application that rapidly generates a complete web application frontend for a database. You configure the options you want, it generates the PHP code.
While you can edit the generated PHP and templates, this is more about creating a web app through configuration rather than coding.

I've used it a lot for rapidly generating administrative interfaces which only need the general CRUD style interace.
http://www.hkvstore.com/phpmaker/

Answer (score 0):

For a rich and high-level framework, you can look into [Agile UI](https://github.com/atk4/ui). It contains many UI components (CRUD, Form, Menu, etc) that will help you take your mind off technical details (such as HTML) and focus on the UI/business logic. Works with MySQL or other data persistences.

p.s. I'm a contributor and will be glad to help.